# ionic file index.html not found

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

when I launch my app in smartphone android I have this error:

> ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND ( file://android_asset/www/index.html)

this is information ionic :

> cli packages: (C:\Users\med\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Node : v6.11.1
npm  : 3.10.10
OS   : Windows 7
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\med\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

I add this in config.xml but also error:

```
<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
```

Comment: every time did you get it?

Comment: yes every time ...

Comment: first of all remove this `<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />`

Comment: okey i remove this .. then !!

Comment: have you using third party libraries?

Comment: I use multiple plugin cordova

Comment: okk then don't put it in the `platform ready` part of `component.ts` file

Comment: yes i don't put in platform ready and this is code platform in component.ts :  platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });

Comment: everything is perfect
now check

Comment: I have this error now : https://imgur.com/a/bixCp

Answer (score 2):

make sure add in config.xml

```
<content src="index.html" />
```

You need to delete node_modules,platform and plugin and then execute following command

```
npm install
cordova platform add android@6.2.3
cordova prepare --save
cordova run android
```

Comment: This is what I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution with was changing the index.html file from

```
    <base href="/" />
```

To:

```
    <base href="." />
```

I'm currently using ionic v6.13.1, node v14.17.5 and android platform is @7.0.0

Answer (score -2):

Upgrade to the latest chrome version on your dev machine and it resolves the issue.

Comment: That is a completely unhelpful answer, unrelated to the problem.